# How do you find the asymptotic time complexity of these loops?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, nested-loops

How do you find the asymptotic time complexity of this code?

```
for i=1 to n do
    j=2
    while j<i do
        j=j*j
```

In my notes I have the answer O(n*log(logn)) but without an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first for loop runs n times. The inner loop iterates in squares and so will take `O(loglogn)` So, total complexity is `O(n*log(logn))`.

To understand why iterating in squares take `O(log(logn))` time, see this way :

Suppose n is as large number as 2^16.

```
Initially: j = 2
1st step : j = 2^2
2nd step : j = 2^4
3rd step : j = 2^8
4th step : j = 2^16.
```

Hence it takes only 4 steps which is loglog(2^16).

So now for any `n = 2^k`, you start with 2 and everytime you are  squaring. So , there can be atmost `O(logk)` squaring you can do to reach k.  Since `n = 2^k`, So, `k = log(n)` and hence `O(logk)` is same as `O(log(logn)).`

Comment: But could you explain with more detail why the inner loops takes O(logn*logn) time?

Comment: @DaMike : Updated the answer with explaination

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it!

Comment: also, you mistyped lognlogn in the beginning but it won't let me edit it (The edit must be at least 10 characters or something)